# Get menu item class in Drupal 7

Tags: class, menu, drupal-7

I´m trying to get menu items `classes/IDs` to be able to write a conditions for front-end.

I tried the following code :

```
$element['#attributes']['class']
```

But it's not showing me anything.

Can you please show me a way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a nice little module to do this if you don't need to hard code them:

https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_attributes